# Yii, trying to get a property of non-object

Tags: php, mysql, yii

just when i knew how to deal with data connections to mysql, i just wanted to echo a simple data from 1 column by specific id, for now i just wanted to show the id as a test, but its really confusing why its giving me this error.

action controller:

```
public function actionTest()
{
    $id = 2;
    $peticion = Peticion::model()->findByPk($id);
    $cotizacion = null; //Cotizacion::model()->findByPk($peticion->cotizacion_id);
    $decreto = null; //Decreto::model()->findByPk($peticion->decreto_id);
    $tipos = null; //Tipos::model()->findByPk($peticion->tipos_id);
    $caracterizacion = null; //Caracterizacion::model()->findByPk($peticion->caracterizacion_id);

    $this->render('test', array(
        'peticion'=>$peticion, 
        'cotizacion'=>$cotizacion, 
        'decreto'=>$decreto, 
        'tipos'=>$tipos,
        'caracterizacion'=>$caracterizacion,
    ));
}
```

the view:

```
<h1>Testing Vars..</h1>

<?php
echo $peticion->id;
?>
```

i just wanted it to show me the id of this table column, no relations are needed for this call cause its just trying to get gathered from the same table, i really dont see what im making this wrong.

Comment: Maybe it's not finding a record? What's the output of `print_r($peticion);`

Comment: Then it's not finding a record. Are you sure there's a record with a primary key of 2?

Comment: sorry, i had to go to the server to see what was the problem, checked on the table and found out that id 2 didnt exist, that was the problem, thanks anyways for your attention